# Why I can't paste anything to the Desktop?

Tags: 20.04, gnome, lts, copy, paste

I use Focal Fossa with Gnome and I have a strange problem with the Desktop.

When I try to drag and drop any files from a library it doesn't allow me to drop it to the Desktop. Copy and Paste doesn't work too.

I can only copy files with the Files application between libraries or with Double Commander.

Edit: Alright, so I was looking for some answers on the internet and a guy said it is not possible to copy anything from the Files to the Desktop because the the system doesn't allow it. Is this true? This is a base function of Windows. I really feel frustrated.

Comment: As far as I know that is the default behaviour

Comment: Is there any way to change it?

Comment: There is the possibility to copy a file to the Desktop directory in the home directory.

Comment: GNOME upstream disabled the function, and yes it is annoying.  The workaround is to open up the file browser, go to your Desktop there, and then paste into that folder.  That'll make it appear on the Desktop.  it's a workaround but it's still annoying they nixed the feature upstream.

Comment: Thanks! I understand they disabled the function, but... is it going to come back in Jammy Jellyfish? Next LTS version coming out at 21th of April.

Comment: @ThomasWard Your comments look more like an answer! 

Comment: That was the main reason I switched to Budgie. "That'll make it appear on the Desktop."  is that something new? Even that did not work last time I used gnome :P @ThomasWard  rowonka: gnome developers made a decision to throw everything out that was not a task for the desktop and depend on "extension" for all other stuff. so it will not get into gnome and someone would need to make an extension for it.